# R problem with fraction numerals

Tags: r

Why do I have a non-zero result in the following calculation:

> 0.11-0.1-0.01 
>   [1] -5.20417e-18

Seems to be an easy and akward question, but I will be very greatful for any help!)

Comment: Its because a computer cannot store decimal numbers with infinite precision. As such, it is not an R problem. Just a problem of using computers. Maybe you can get some impression on how it is done in general in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format.

Comment: This is R FAQ 7.31: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html

Answer (score -2):

You can multiply with (X==)10/100/1000/... to size of precision you want. After performing multiplication to both numbers, Do your operation(-, /, ...) You will get the result.